# Регулярное выражение для email - найти в тексте без определенного символа

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, имеется регулярное выражение:

```
(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)
```

С помощью данного выражения возможно найти в тексте все упоминания e-mail адресов. Возможно ли изменить данное выражение, чтобы возможно было найти все упоминания e-mail адресов, но, где до упоминания e-mail не встречается символ "|".

Т.е. исходный текст имеет вид:

```
|данные|данные|moy_mail@mail.ru|данные|данные|Текст_материала_статьи ... (в тексте вставлен e-mail@mail.ru) ... какой-то текст...
```

Представлены данные сайта в текстовом варианте, требуется найти в данных все упоминания e-mail, которые расположены внутри статей_материалов сайта, при этом исключить e-mail, которые заключены в иных данных (e-mail в данном случае располагается между символами "|").

Возможно найти все e-mail адреса, которые расположены внутри символов "|", при помощи регулярного выражения:

```
([|]\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)
```

Только требуется выполнить обратное, найти все e-mail не установленные внутри данных символов.

Comment: *С помощью данного выражения возможно найти в тексте все упоминания e-mail адресов.* — хм. подозреваю, что вы не видели примера генерации (именно генерации) огромаднейшего регулярного выражения (в [книге Фридла](http://www.books.ru/books/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-3-e-izdanie-592346/)), которым **действительно** можно найти адрес электронной почты в строке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не усложнять вашу регулярку, то решение весьма простое:

`[^|\w](\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)`

Ищем e-mail'ы, которые не начинаются с разделителя или разрешенного вами набора символов.

На **[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wB6kD8/1)** можно посмотреть на пример работы.

*p.s. не забудьте удалить 1 лишний символ слева, попавший в общую группу захвата.*

Comment: Спасибо большое, решение помогло!